# When I run my code, the variables still have the value that they were given in the beggining. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Product{
    
    //Class attributes
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int score; 
    
    public Product() {
        name = "";
        score = 0; 
        price = 1;
    }
    
    public void printData(){
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Price: " + price);
        System.out.println("Score: " + score);
    }
    
    
    public void read() {
        
        Scanner in  = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Product name: ");
        String name = in.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("Price: ");
        double price = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Score: ");
        int core = in.nextInt();
    }
    
    public boolean is_better_than(Product other) {
        
        if (score/price > other.score/other.price)
            return true;
         
        return false;
        
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
        Scanner in  = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        Product best = new Product();
        
        boolean more = true;
        while(more) {
            
            
            Product current = new Product();
            
            current.read(); // 
            if (current.is_better_than(best)) {
                best = current;
            }
                            
            System.out.println("More Products? 1:YES, 2:NO");
            int answer  = in.nextInt();
            if (answer != 1)
                more = false;
            in.nextLine();
        
        }
        
        best.printData(); 
    }
}
```

When i type a name, a score and a price it displays what the prices that the variables were given at the beggining of the programm instead of the new ones

Comment: In `Product.read()`, doing `String name = in.nextLine();` is declaring a new _local variable_. It is not assigning the value to the name _field_. Try just `name = in.nextLine();` (and same for the other fields you want to assign values to).

Answer (score 3):

In the read method you have created local variables for name price and core. You are reading into these local variables instead of into the member variables (fields) of your class.

Instead of

```java
        String name = in.nextLine(); 
        double price = in.nextDouble();
        int core = in.nextInt();
```

You should do

```java
        this.name = in.nextLine(); 
        this.price = in.nextDouble();
        this.core = in.nextInt();
```

Now that we've removed the local variables we are no longer shadowing the instance variables. We can therefore omit `this.` in the solution above so could do

```java
        name = in.nextLine(); 
        price = in.nextDouble();
        core = in.nextInt();
```

Comment: If there is no ambiguity because of a locally scoped variable whose name shadows the instance variable name, the `this.` is extraneous.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared new *local* variables to store the input data, rather than assigning to the instance variables.

```
    public void read() {     
        Scanner in  = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Product name: ");
        name = in.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("Price: ");
        price = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Score: ");
        core = in.nextInt();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> *"... When i type a name, a score and a price it displays what the prices that the variables were given at the beggining of the programm instead of the new ones ..."*

You don't have to re-declare the values, in the *read* method.

```java
public void read() {

    Scanner in  = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Product name: ");
    name = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Price: ");
    price = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Score: ");
    score = in.nextInt();
}
```

Output

```
Product name: 
abc
Price: 
1.23
Score: 
123
More Products? 1:YES, 2:NO
2
Name: abc
Price: 1.23
Score: 123
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create getters and setters to call them when you're going to change the values or show them in your main method:

```
//Constructor above...

public String getName() {
       return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
}   

public String getPrice() {
       return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
       this.price= price;
}

public String getScore() {
       return score;
}

public void setScore(String score) {
       this.score= score;
}
```